# useContext() is undefined when i use useLocation()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, runtime-error, use-context

I'm working on a website using React.
I'm getting this error when using useContext() and useLocation().

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import Layout from "../components/Layout";
import { LangStateContext } from "../context/LangContext";

import { useLocation } from 'react-router';


const PricingPage = () => {
  const { isIndoSelected } = useContext(LangStateContext);
  console.log(isIndoSelected);

  const location = useLocation();


  return (
    <Layout>
      a page
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default PricingPage;
```

This is the error im getting when i land on the page

[image: useContext is undefined error]

Can anyone explain to me why this wont work and what a good workaround would be?

Thanks you

Comment: Any luck finding a solution ? I've just encountered this problem : useContext becomes undefined when I add useLocation. But if I comment the useLocation line, no more problem...

Answer (score 1):

`useContext` needs Providers to work, so make sure that you have instantiated one that has this component as a direct or indirect child.

Also make sure that the context that you have created to instantiate this provider has this `isIndoSelected` that you're trying to access.

You can read more about React's Context usage [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used "useContext" in combination with "isIndoSelected" on many other page without any issue. Its the "useLocation" that breaks it, this is what i don't understand.

Comment: How are your providers organized? Are you sure that this page is somehow descendant to any provider?

Comment: Yes im sure, other pages and this page works fine without the use of useLocation(). The moment i declare location with useLocation(), useContext is undefined.